# forbid compilation if property of an object is "bigger" than another in c#

Tags: c#

I basically don't want to allow compilation if someone makes a specific property of an object bigger than another property of that same object. can I do that? Kind of like:

```
class Class1 {
    public int property1 { set; get; }
    public int property2 { set; get; }

    public void method (Class1 obj) {
        if (obj.property1 < obj.property2) {
            //won't compile!
        }
    }
}

class Class2 {
    static void Main() {
        Class1 obj = new Class1();
        obj.property1 = 10;
        obj.property2 = 11;
        obj.method(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: No you can't. Example: `obj.property1 = new Random().Next()` - now what does the compiler do?

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to check is a **runtime** operation, which cannot be done by a compiler.

The closest you can get to what you need to do is by using the C# `sizeof` operator which checks the size of the property in bytes.